# How do you add toggle functionality to a wishlist button to add and remove items from a wishlist?

Tags: javascript

```js
var wishlistkey = "wishlist";
// try and fetch an existing wishlist from the localStorage.
var wish_list = localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey);
console.log(wish_list,$.isEmptyObject(wish_list));
if ($.isEmptyObject(wish_list)) { //nothing was saved previously
  wish_list = [];
} else {
  wish_list = JSON.parse(wish_list);
  count_items_in_wishlist_update();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  $(".wishlist").on("click", function() {
    const office_id = $(this).attr("office_id"),
    office_name = $(this).attr("office_name"),
    office_str = `<tr class="wishlist-item" id="list_id_${office_id}"><td class="w-pname">${office_name}</td><td class="w-premove" wpid="${office_id}">x</td></tr>`;
    //check if the element is in the array
    const found = $.inArray(office_id, wish_list) > -1;
    if (found) {
      $("#list_id_" + office_id).remove();
      wish_list = wish_list.filter(id => id != office_id);
      show_message(office_name + " Office Removed");
    }
    else {
      $("#wish_list_item").append(office_str);
      wish_list.push(office_id);
      show_message(office_name + " Office Added");
    }
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });

  //adding toggle functionality to the wishlist pannel
  $(".wish_list_heading").on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("up")) {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "390px");
      $(this).addClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "auto");
    } else {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "35px");
      $(this).removeClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }

  });
  // Remove function
  $("#wish_list_item").on("click", ".w-premove", function() {
    office_id = $(this).attr("wpid");
    $("#list_id_" + office_id).remove();
    wish_list = wish_list.filter(id => id != office_id);
    show_message("Office removed");
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });
});
//Animation 
function show_message($msg) {
  $("#msg").html($msg);
  $top = Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#msg").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  $left = Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#msg").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px";
  $("#msg").css("left", $left);
  $("#msg").animate({
    opacity: 0.6,
    top: $top
  }, 400, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#msg").animate({
      opacity: 0.6,
      top: "0px"
    }, 400, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 2000);
}

//Validation against the amount of product being added
function count_items_in_wishlist_update() {
  $("#p_label").html(wish_list.length > 0 ? "My Shortlist ("+wish_list.length+")" : "My Shortlist"); 
  $('#wish_list_item').empty();
  $(".wishlist").each(function(index, el) {  
    const office_id = $(el).attr("office_id");
    const found = wish_list.includes(office_id);
    console.log(office_id,wish_list,found);
    const $heart = $(el).find(".fa");
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart",found);
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart-o",!found);
    if (found) {
    const office_name = $(el).attr("office_name"),
    office_str = `<tr class="wishlist-item" id="list_id_${office_id}"><td class="w-pname">${office_name}</td><td class="w-premove" wpid="${office_id}">x</td></tr>`;
      $('#wish_list_item').append(office_str);
    }  
  });
  localStorage.setItem(wishlistkey, JSON.stringify(wish_list));
}
```

I have made a wishlist where I add items to a wishlist by a button and remove the items from within the wishlist itself by pressing a cross next to the item. However, I need the button to add AND remove items too by having a toggle functionality on the button itself. Also if possible, I would like to have a hyperlink added to the wishlist item. I really haven't got a clue to do that. Can anybody help?

```js
var wishlistkey = "wishlist";
// try and fetch an existing wishlist from the localStorage.
var wish_list = []; // localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey)

if ($.isEmptyObject(wish_list)) { //nothing was saved previously
  wish_list = new Array()
} else {
  wish_list = JSON.parse(wish_list);
  count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  $('#wish_list_item').html(wish_list);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wishlist").on("click", function() {
    $data = "";
    $office_id = $(this).attr("office_id");
    $office_name = $(this).attr("office_name");
    $office_str = "<tr class='wishlist-item' id='list_id_" + $office_id + "'><td class='w-pname'>" + $office_name + "</td><td class='w-premove' wpid='" + $office_id + "'>x</td></tr>";
    //check if the element is in the array
    if ($.inArray($office_id, wish_list) == -1) {


      $("#wish_list_item").append($office_str);

      wish_list.push($office_str);
      //  localStorage.setItem(wishlistkey, JSON.stringify(wish_list))
      show_message($office_name + " Office Added");
    }
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });

  //adding toggle functionality to the wishlist pannel
  $(".wish_list_heading").on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("up")) {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "390px");
      $(this).addClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "auto");
    } else {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "35px");
      $(this).removeClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }

  });
  // Remove function
  $("#wish_list_item").on("click", ".w-premove", function() {
    $office_id = $(this).attr("wpid");
    $("#list_id_" + $office_id).remove();
    wish_list = [];

    $("tr.wishlist-item").each(function(index, el) {
      wish_list.push(el.outerHTML);
    });
    //localStorage.setItem(wishlistkey, JSON.stringify(wish_list));

    show_message("Office removed");
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();

  });
});
//Animation 
function show_message($msg) {
  $("#msg").html($msg);
  $top = Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#msg").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  $left = Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#msg").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px";
  $("#msg").css("left", $left);
  $("#msg").animate({
    opacity: 0.6,
    top: $top
  }, 400, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#msg").animate({
      opacity: 0.6,
      top: "0px"
    }, 400, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 2000);
}

//Validation against the amount of product being added
function count_items_in_wishlist_update() {
  $("#listitem").html(wish_list.length);
  if (wish_list.length > 1) {
    $("#p_label").html("Shortlist (");
  } else {
    $("#p_label").html("Shortlist (");
  }
}
```

```css
button a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

button {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  margin: 0 5px 0;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
}

#wish_list {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #22a7c5;
  z-index: 3;
}

#wish_list .wish_list_heading {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: #22a7c5;
  padding: 6px 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#wish_list_item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 0px 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#msg {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #22a7c5;
  border: 1px solid #22a7c5;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
}

.wishlist-item {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #323470;
}

.w-premove {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 7%;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.w-pname {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 93%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='msg'></div>
<div id='wish_list' class='col-s'>
  <p class="wish_list_heading">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    <span id='p_label'>Shortlist (</span>
    <span id='listitem'>0</span>
    <span id='p_label'>)</span>
  </p>
  <table id='wish_list_item' border='0'></table>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='Hampton Street' office_id='hamptonstreet'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-heart">❤️</i></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet crashes with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`; Could you please close the missing `})`, and also add the relevant HTML, so we can see the problem?

Comment: You need to provide the html and import the Jquery in your script to make it work as well.

Comment: Should be a heart, I just left the background white so you can't see the button

Comment: @mplungjan I've gone back to a code that you done that worked well but the problem is, when I navigate to another page to say add another office to the wishlist, the office in the wishlist that I saved before is not there. The count number is there but the details of the office in the wishlist dissapears. The weird thing is, when I go back to the page where I added the office, the office shows up again in the wishlist. I edited the post to show the code that you did that works well.  If you could help that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Did you uncomment the `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` lines?

Comment: isEmptyObject is testing an object. It is not an object but a string. Change to `const wishlistkey = "wishlist";
let wish_list = localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey);
wish_list = wish_list ? JSON.parse(wish_list) : []; count_items_in_wishlist_update();`

Comment: @mplungjan Its not working. My original js that I posted originally worked perfectly wwhen refreshing the page and when I went to a new url......it remembered everything. Maybe we should start again from that original code. All I need added to the code is a simple toggle heart that adds AND removes the office from the wishlist. At present, with the original code adds the office when pressing the button over and over again.......I just want a toggle heart that adds and removes on toggle. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work is not a great description- look in the console perhaps I had a typo

Comment: I cannot comment. Your code does not look like mine so I cannot determine what is wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, how about this. With the original code, can you just make it so that when you press the heart it just adds one. In other words, if the item is already in the wishlist.....don't add it again. That would be good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated version

You need to push the ID and test that.

Also I simplified the count_items_in_wishlist_update

NOTE: Remember to uncomment the localStorage statements when uploading to your server

I update the localstorage only in one place now

Test the code here: https://plungjan.name/SO/lslike/

```js
const offices = {
  "hamptonstreet": {
    office_name: 'Hampton Street',
    office_url: 'https://hamptonstreet.co.uk'
  },
  "kensingtonstreet": {
    office_name: 'Kensington Street',
    office_url: 'https://kensingtonstreet.co.uk'
  }
};

document.querySelector('.btn-group').innerHTML = Object.entries(offices).map(([key, office]) => `<button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='${office.office_name}' office_id='${key}'>
    <span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>${office.office_name}</button>`).join('')

const wishlistkey = "wishlist";
// try and fetch an existing wishlist from the localStorage.
let wish_list = null; // localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey) // uncomment and remove null

wish_list = wish_list ? JSON.parse(wish_list) : []

count_items_in_wishlist_update();

$(document).ready(function() {
  count_items_in_wishlist_update(); // show what is already in wishlist

  $(".wishlist").on("click", function() {
    const office_id = $(this).attr("office_id"),
      office = offices[office_id];
    //check if the element is in the array
    const found = $.inArray(office_id, wish_list) > -1
    if (found) {
      $(`#list_id_${office_id}`).remove()
      show_message(office.office_name + " Office Removed");
    } else {
      wish_list.push(office_id);
      show_message(office.office_name + " Office Added");
    }
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });

  //adding toggle functionality to the wishlist pannel
  $(".wish_list_heading").on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("up")) {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "390px");
      $(this).addClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "auto");
    } else {
      $("#wish_list").css("height", "35px");
      $(this).removeClass("up");
      $("#wish_list").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }

  });
  // Remove function
  $("#wish_list_item").on("click", ".w-premove", function() {
    office_id = $(this).attr("wpid");
    $("#list_id_" + office_id).remove();
    wish_list = wish_list.filter(id => id != office_id);
    show_message("Office removed");
    count_items_in_wishlist_update();
  });
});
//Animation 
function show_message($msg) {
  $("#msg").html($msg);
  $top = Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#msg").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  $left = Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#msg").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px";
  $("#msg").css("left", $left);
  $("#msg").animate({
    opacity: 0.6,
    top: $top
  }, 400, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }).show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#msg").animate({
      opacity: 0.6,
      top: "0px"
    }, 400, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 2000);
}

//Validation against the amount of product being added
function count_items_in_wishlist_update() {
  $("#p_label").html(wish_list.length > 0 ? "Shortlist (" + wish_list.length + ")" : "Shortlist");
  $('#wish_list_item').empty();
  $(".wishlist").each(function(index, el) {
    const office_id = $(el).attr("office_id");
    const found = wish_list.includes(office_id);
    //    console.log(office_id,wish_list,found)
    const $heart = $(el).find(".fa");
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart", found);
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart-o", !found);
    if (found) {
      const office_id = $(el).attr("office_id"),
        office = offices[office_id],
        office_str = `<tr class="wishlist-item" id="list_id_${office_id}"><td class="w-pname"><a href="${office.office_url}">${office.office_name}</a></td><td class="w-premove" wpid="${office_id}">x</td></tr>`;
      $('#wish_list_item').append(office_str);
    }
  })
  // localStorage.setItem(wishlistkey, JSON.stringify(wish_list)); // uncomment 
}
```

```css
button a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

button {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  margin: 0 5px 0;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
}

#wish_list {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #22a7c5;
  z-index: 3;
}

#wish_list .wish_list_heading {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: #22a7c5;
  padding: 6px 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#wish_list_item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 0px 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#msg {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #22a7c5;
  border: 1px solid #22a7c5;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
}

.wishlist-item {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #323470;
}

.w-premove {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 7%;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.w-pname {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 93%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<div id='msg'></div>
<div id='wish_list' class='col-s'>
  <p class="wish_list_heading">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    <span id='p_label'>Shortlist</span>
  </p>
  <table id='wish_list_item' border='0'></table>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.....thats great! Do you know how to change the heart symbol on toggle too please so it shows a outlined heart at first and then a full heart when selected? Thanks. So fa fa-heart-o and then fa fa-heart

Comment: Hi mplungjan, It does work but when I refresh the page, the shortlist doesn't remember the item that was in the shortlist....it did remember with my original code before. Also, I was hoping that when I remove an item in the shortlist with the (x), it would return the heart icon to its original state. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have UNCOMMENTED them but still not doing it.

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't know what you mean by update my html?

Comment: I wanted more items in the HTML in the question. I have anyway been able to finish. It now only updates localStorage in one place as it should do. You can test is here: https://plungjan.name/SO/lslike/

Comment: When you say remove null how should it be written? var wish_list = null;

Comment: I've done it and thank you soooo much......its perfect!!!!!! ; )

Comment: `var wish_list = localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey)`

Comment: Hard work :)....

Comment: Do you know how to add a link to the item name? I want to have a link on Hampton street in the wishlist so it links to the hampton street page?

Comment: Sure. Where does the href come from. You can change `${office_name}` to `<a href="$someURL}">${office_name}</a>`

Comment: Ok that sounds good. How do I put the url in the html so that the js will pick up the url?

Comment: that is up to you. I would personally have an object of things: `const listOfThings : { "hamptonstreet": { "officeName": "Hampton Street", "url": "https://hamptonstreet.co.uk" }, "otherstreet": { "officeName": "Other Street", "url": "https://otherstreet.co.uk" }  }` then you can address into the list using office id

Comment: Hi mplungjan, could you show me how to do this please? I can't seem to do it?

Comment: How do you fill your <div class="btn-group"> now?

Comment: Its in the html above....the last 5 rows

Comment: <div class="btn-group">
  <button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='Hampton Street' office_id='hamptonstreet'>
    <span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>
  </button>
</div>

Comment: So you do NOT use an object or a loop over streets? You must have more than one street no?

Comment: And where do you get the URLs from?

Comment: Each html is placed on the specific office page. Yes I do have different offices but each html for the individual office page has its own html on it. The url would be the the office page url but I’m trying to work out how to adjust the html so that the js picks it up like it picks up the office id etc

Comment: Why not have one object you load it in one page and you can generate different page

Comment: I was hoping to just add the link code into the html like how the name of the office is done and then add that to the js to pick up. I really wouldn’t have a clue how to do a js list and one object?

Comment: See update.....

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understand what I mean. I want just a heart on the webpage but I want the link to the webpage in the actual wishlist. So when you press the heart, the office name Hampton Street will go to the wishlist. But the Hampton Street name in the wishlist will have a link to the webpage. I would also prefer this link to be in the html like before....not in js const. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: So change the code. It’s all there now

Comment: Sorry I just can't do it. All I want is the office name with the office page url to be in the html. There will be multiple pages with all different names and urls so it would be easier for me to put this in the html and for js to pick it up. So it will be like this as it was before but with the url      <div class="btn-group">
      <button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='Hampton Street' 

office_id='hamptonstreet'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>
      </button>
</div>

Comment: Ok, updated. Note I removed unused data - we only need to add in one place

Comment: Sorry, I really don't think you understand what I mean. Your html only has this:  <div class="btn-group">   but I want it to be like this: <div class="btn-group">
  <button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='Hampton Street' office_id='hamptonstreet'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-heart">❤️</i></span>
      </button>  I want the url to be in this html so that I can have different html contents for each page. I don#t know how to do it your way with just js. It may be easier for you but I simply can't do it. Is there a way to have the html like this:

Comment: So you want to LOAD the HTML of the page they click into the shortlist? That was never clear from your descriptions! You never showed more information anywhere than what I show.

Comment: You could do `$('#wish_list_item').append(office_str); $(\`#list_id_${office_id} td.w-pname\`).load(office.office_url);` instead of the link

Comment: Your html only has this:  <div class="btn-group"> I want the url to be in the html so that I can have different html contents for each page. I don't know how to do it your way with just js. See example below...notice this in brackets (office_url='some-url) added below.  : <div class="btn-group">
  <button class='wishlist' title="Add To Shortlist" office_name='Hampton Street' office_id='hamptonstreet' office_url='some-url'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-heart">❤️</i></span>
      </button>

Comment: I am sorry. I give up. You cannot explain what you need in a manner I can use to help you and I cannot code simply enough for you to implement what you want

Comment: I know, you have done enough and what you have done is great and I really appreciate it.  I just wanted the name that goes to the actual wishlist to be clickable and have a link to the office page. i can see you have done it in js but I don't understand js that well hence the reason I am here. I wanted the html for the page to contain the link/url and for the js to pick it up and put that in the actual wishlist.....exactly the same way the name of the office is picked up by js and put into the actual wish list. But thanks all the same anyway and sorry to waste your time. : )

Comment: I understand the issue now. There is no data on page2 from page 1. So we cannot copy the page1 data in the popup on page2. We need an object with all offices on each page

Comment: This is better but not complete https://plungjan.name/SO/lslike/