# save attribute from button to localstorage and get it into table

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can i save this atrr from button to local storage and get it into table :

```
<button class='myData' title="Add To data" data_nama='kantorku' data_id='kantor' data_link='https://www.kantor.com'>
      <span><i class="fa-light fa-star"></i></span>
    </button>
```

when that button is click , will save to localstorage like this :

```
[{"data-id": "kantorku", "data-nama":  "Kantorku", "data-link" : "https://...."}]
```

after save, i will getItem and show into table `.append(showIntoTable)`

i'm confuse for javascript code, i try tutor from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447055/how-do-you-add-toggle-functionality-to-a-wishlist-button-to-add-and-remove-items) but no working if save from attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your data attributes need an apostrophe not underscore (data-nama not data_nama). Then on load get the localstorage storage and convert it to a JSON array using JSON parse.

I'm looping through the dataset so that it can be dynamic and accept more or less objects.

Then push it to the new variable then override the localstorage item with the stringify version.

```
<button class='myData' title="Add To data" data-nama='kantorku' data-id='kantor' data-link='https://www.kantor.com'>
     BUTTON
    </button>

let savedDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved") || "[]");
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("myData")) {
    let data = {};
    for( var d in el.dataset)
      data["data-" + d] = el.dataset[d]
      savedDate.push(data)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("saved",JSON.stringify(savedDate))
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and i try and see in 'inspect' its work. How can i modif the code when the button is clicked and store data to local storage than button color change color and toggle to remove function. i mean one button with toggle function for add and remove like sample in link i share before. So, we can know that the button has store to localstorage and we can remove it by click again the same button.

Comment: @zet.io I would ask a new question for that as that is something outside of your original question.

Comment: i see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447055/how-do-you-add-toggle-functionality-to-a-wishlist-button-to-add-and-remove-items and maybe want to make like that but not working